# ng-repeat not refreshing in select options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat

Currently working with AngularJS, I have a problem with a 'select-options'.

I'm doing a $http request to fetch data from a Cloud SQL database.

To do this, I call a function which is in my factory and that returns the data from my DB.

[Here is my JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAWC1.png).

As you can see, I first initialize my 'controller.connections' variable with an array of 2 values (1 and 2).

After fetching my data (with my 'f_getData' function), I change the value of that array (I add 4 values and I don't use the data I fetch just to test, but the behaviour is the same).

[Here is my HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shfQ5.png).

For your information, my ng-app is on the 'html' tag, and ng-controller is on the 'body' tag.
I'm using ng-repeat for my options because I had the same behaviour using ng-options.
Right underneath my select I have a ng-repeat with the exact same condition to test.

[Here is the behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meTYx.png).

As you can see, my variable that is in my ng-repeat for my select doesn't seem to be updated.
Although, that same variable is updated on the ng-repeat on the 'p' tag.

So I tried :

1. $scope.$apply() in the callback ('then'), but console says $digest is being done. I also tried after the callback, it says that $apply() is being done, so I tried a $timeout of 2 seconds which didn't do anything.
2. $scope.connections instead of controller.connections, but I guess that generates a problem because ng-repeat creates its own scope.
3. Using a temporary variable for my big array in the callback, then changing the value of my 'connections' variable to this temporary variable out of the callback, and finaly calling $scope.$apply(). The ng-repeat on my options is not updated, but my ng-repeat on the 'p' tag is.

So basically my problem is : I can't use ng-repeat nor ng-options to create a dynamic select input.
Does anyone have a solution ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a question, why your interpolation is done with brackets and not curly braces ?

Comment: @Zooly, we can use interpolateprovider to change the default , stephane, can you create a [plunker] (https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) for this issue

Comment: @SunilLama oh ok, I didn't know this point, very interesting, thanks!

Comment: @Stephare, You can use a timeout method with less amount of time will rebind the ng-option values.

Comment: Make plunker with your files and I promise I'll solve your problem.

Comment: @Zooly I'm using flask for my python backend, and this framework allows me to pass variable from front to back. So in my front, if I say {{ variable }}, we don't know if it's from flask or angular because they have the same synthax.

Comment: Yes I understand :) Didn't know you were using Flask backend

Comment: @Sathiyaraj the time I wait in my timeout doesn't change at all the behaviour but thanks for trying

Comment: @SunilLama I'm not sure I can create a plunker that recreates this behaviour because I use an http request on a route defined in my Python back, but I'll check out if I can

Comment: @StéphaneC with plunker it will be easy to debug your code

Comment: @SunilLama I understand that a plunker will help, yet I can't reproduce my problem because the problem comes from the answer from an http request on an url to my backend in flask. And the problem comes from where I get the answer to this http request

Comment: @StéphaneC, i had created an example of customInterpolation take this plunker as a reference. [interpolation](https://plnkr.co/edit/GAStnqcVN4I9hFiz32rT?p=info) for help

Comment: @SunilLama As I said, the problem doesn't come from this, but from the callback of an http request. Nothing to do with customInterpolation.

Comment: oh zeez @StéphaneC buddy, i am asking you to use those to have your code copy pasted so that we can debug it.

Comment: @SunilLama https://plnkr.co/edit/9golzCHr6dIUX7gY3nCb?p=preview
This is the plunker I created from your example.But it works. As I said, I cannot reproduce my problem with a plunker because the problem comes from a callback after calling a Python method, and I cannot simply copy and paste Python code.

Answer (score 0):

To all of you who tried to help me, thank you very much. 
I resolved my problem (with a bit of change). 
I started to use the old school awful way to fill a select with options by creating the options element in my JS while I would find a solution. While looking for a way to reset the value of my select, I found a plunker of someone who was using ng-options and it was working. I therefore took the code of this plunker and pasted it in my code.
And it worked !
Then I tried to adapt it to my code and it worked till a certain point.
That point was the div where my select was. I tried to put it in a few different places (working) till the div it was at the beginning (works a bit :sometimes when I refresh, options would not show, then refreshing again would solve the problem).
I'm still trying to figure out what was the problem.
Thanks everybody for your help.
I'm sorry for giving you screenshots of my code, I'm not familiar with posting questions here, I'm that kind of guy using the answers rather than finding them...
But I assure you that I take note of all of your critics for my future questions.

Thanks again !

P.S : How do we close a subject, please ? ^^